# PowerShell script cannot create file when called using informatica

Tags: powershell, informatica

I have a PowerShell script which is called using Informatica which will create some output files which was working fine and Suddenly the script can't create the output files when it was called from informatica but works fine when it is run directly Powershell console. What could be the issue in this case?

Comment: Can you show us any message from the script or does it fail silently?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any parameters in the script? It's possible those are not available in the shell when script is called thru Informatica. Try debugging by hardcoding the values.